# How to install Python from .tar.xz using windows command Prompt

Tags: python, installation, cmd, python-install

I wanted to install  Python 3.5.5, I only found compressed files as shown below.

[image]

when I wanted to intall it using

> pip install Python-3.5.5.tar.xz
> or
> pip install Python-3.5.5.tgz

I had these errors

[image]

Comment: you need tar to extract those files .. if you have git for windows, `tar zxvf  Python-3.5.5.tgz` should do the trick .. however, i do have doubts that the file you have is the correct one as tar packages usually are just source code and then you need proper compiler to make that into a working python interpreter

Comment: @rasjani yes actually I have extracted the files and when I write pip install Python-3.5.5 it writes  ERROR: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python-3.5.5
               ERROR:No matching distribution found for Python-3.5.5

Comment: @rasjani, just for information, tar.exe has been a built-in utility since Windows 10. There's no need to install git.

Comment: tar -xvzf  Python-3.7.10.tgz

Answer (score 0):

apparently, you are using some advance version like python 3.12.0 and pip 23.2.1 to install an older version like Python 3.5.5. This kind of issue is probably because the advanced version could not process some of the text present in setup file or files associated with that setup. I will recommend you use the version which closely similar to 3.5.5 and has a windows installer with it. or install a python version like 3.7.9 and then using that install 3.5.5.

however, if you just trying to extract a tgz file the then you can use the following.

download the Python-3.5.5.tgz file. and let's say the path it has got downloaded is "C:\Users\user\Downloads" then run the following line on your terminal.

> tar -xvzf "C:\Users\khalid\Downloads\Python-3.5.5.tgz"

this will extract the tgz file

Answer (score -1):

You can find the installers for windows here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

The file you have is not suitable for installing on Windows.

Comment: yes, actually that's from where I got the files for python 3.5.5 version, I only found compressed files

Comment: It seems that there are no installers for that version, there is only the source code, you can try looking for the version in other web pages (I don't recommend it) or download another version like 3.5.4: https://www.python.org/ downloads/release/python-354/

Comment: I ve just installed 3.5.4rc1 version and it was succesufully installed, but when using it as an interpreter on  pycharm, it tells me that python 3.5 reached its end of life date and it is no longer supported in Pycharm.. so I suppose that I cannot develop using older versions?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: python.org only provides installers for current/latest releases. Not for older releases. See "No installers" sections in all older release download pages.